# Returning DataFrames headers after features selection using Pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I used Pandas to read the dataset from (.csv) file. The size of the orignal_data is (3185,158) as follows:

```
original _data = pd.read_csv("file path")
print("Original_data_shape:", original _data.shape)
```

The original dataset appears the data frame with the headers as follows:

[image]

Then:

I applied the features selection process from [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) to reduce the number of irrelevant features (i.e., removing irrelevant columns).

```
sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))
original_data = sel.fit_transform(orignal_data )
orignial_data = pd.DataFrame(original_data )
print("Orignial_data_after feature selection size:", original_data .shape)
print("Orignial_data_after feature selection:\n", original_data )
```

The output size is (3185,63) such that we removed the irrelevant columns.

The output data frames as follows:

[image]

However, this final output has no header's names of the selected columns, just index numbers from 0~62 as shown in the red box.
My question is: how I can return the correct header's names of these selected columns?

Updated Code [works correctly]:

```
feature_names = list(original_data.columns.values)
sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))
original_data = sel.fit_transform(original_data)
cols= sel.get_support(indices=True)
selected_features = []
for i in range(len(cols)):
    selected_features.append(feature_names[cols[i]])
orignial_data = pd.DataFrame(original_data, columns= selected_features)
print("Orignial_data_after feature selection size:", original_data .shape)
print("Orignial_data_after feature selection:\n", original_data )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))
cols = original_data.columns
original_data = sel.fit_transform(orignal_data )
orignial_data = pd.DataFrame(original_data, columns = cols)
print("Orignial_data_after feature selection size:", original_data .shape)
print("Orignial_data_after feature selection:\n", original_data )
```

Comment: No, this is not works. It gives me an error that the size is different.
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3185, 63), indices imply (3185, 158). I think this is because the features selection process randomly (every run) reduces the number of columns. How I can return the correct names of the selected columns?

Comment: I solved this issue and updated my code above. [Closed]

Answer (score 0):

Before performing the transformation, you can hold the columns in a variable.

```
original_data_cols = original_data.columns
```

Then after transformation, you can set it as:

```
original_data.columns = original_data_cols
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_support() function from the selector to check if the value satisfies the condition of the selector or not. If a column has low variance then the entire column will be having False and thus we can select only columns with True and that's what has been done on line 3.

```
sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))
modified_data = sel.fit_transform(orignal_data)
cols = original_data.loc[:, sel.get_support()].columns
final_data = pd.DataFrame(modified_data, columns = cols)
print("Final_data_after feature selection size:", final_data.shape)
print("Final_data_after feature selection:\n", final_data)
```

Comment: You can also use this. It's more efficient.